# Upgrading Azure API Management service to premium plan Downtime

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Does anyone know if there is any downtime when upgrading an APIM instance from standard to premium tier?

I have been looking for documentation but cannot see anything that relates.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading/Downgrading Azure APIM has downtime. As mentioned in the documentation "*The upgrade or scale process can take from 15 to 45 minutes to apply. You get notified when it is done.*"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/upgrade-and-scale

Comment: It's worth noting the documentation says there's only downtime if you are upgrading or downgrading to or from the Developer tier.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is not documented, there will be no downtime for upgrading the pricing tier.

Comment: Please add where you are getting this information from. Single sentence answers are frowned upon on the site.

Comment: @BrianH. The process of upgrading is a bunch of implementation details that the team doesn't publish.  Suffice it to say the premium instance is prepped before switching over.

Comment: I have tested this theory and trying to continuously call it whilst upgrading to a premium tier has returned, and is continuing to return a number of failed attempts. So it appears there is down time when changing tier.

Answer (score 0):

There IS definitely downtime. I just upgraded from Developer to Basic and we had a 30 mins downtime in the API while the process finished, so plan this procedure accordingly.